# Excel xlsx displaying value different than underlying xml after saving with Openpyxl Python code

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xml, openpyxl

After using openpyxl to save an xlsx file, some values with a particular format are converted to Unicode characters when viewing with Excel but it is not this way in the underlying xml. I do not want these values to change.

I am using openpyxl 3.0.7 and am reluctant to upgrade due to my system configuration so haven't tested with a newer version. I have been unsuccessful with Googling for this specific issue. I am having unexpected bad results dealing with strings that happen to be match Unicode values when surrounded by underscores. My data is all Unicode text.

In my source xlsx file, I have the text value **Data_x4331_Problem** in a cell (and others like that in other cells, with lowercase x, 4 digit code, surrounded by underscores). The cells are formatted as text. When viewing in Excel it looks like this, and when viewing the underlying xml it also looks like this. If I query the value using openpyxl the same value is returned.

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Temp\Stack\StackExchange_Test.xlsx", read_only="True")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
print(ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value)
wb.close()
```

Result:
Data_x4331_Problem

However, when I use openpyxl (or Pandas) to **save** the file I get some strange results. The value shown in Excel changes to **Data䌱Problem**, while the underlying xml still shows **Data_x4331_Problem**. The new / wrong character replaces *x4331* (with underscores not shown here for some reason) and is the Unicode character for that number according to https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/character-tables/unicode-4000-4fff. When I search for the cell value using the same method as above it still returns Data_x4331_Problem before and after saving.

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Temp\Stack\StackExchange_Test.xlsx", read_only="True")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
print(ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value)
wb.close()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Temp\Stack\StackExchange_Test.xlsx")
wb.save(r"C:\Temp\Stack\StackExchange_Test_Saved.xlsx")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Temp\Stack\StackExchange_Test_Saved.xlsx", read_only="True")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
print(ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value)
wb.close()
```

Results:
Data_x4331_Problem
Data_x4331_Problem

There are differences in the xml files, including the top line in the first 'clean' example. Some changes are expected of course. But 1) I can't understand why Excel is reading a different value than the xml which holds the data, and 2) Why does openpyxl(?) change how the file looks / behaves etc? Or maybe this isn't openpyxl's problem at all...? In my real data I also have Data_X4331_Problem (with uppercase X) and it is unchanged throughout. I cannot change these particular cells by converting case etc for reasons...

My expected end result is that the value shown in Excel before saving via a Python script is the same as the value shown after, when I haven't instructed any changes on the file other than saving.

Edit - I've also tested using Pandas to open and then save the file, but the output file also showed the wrong value in Excel while keeping the correct value in the underlying xml. Very frustrating.

Comment: The problem is basically related to using _xXXXX_ to escape unicode on XML.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, @CharlieClark. Currently to work with these files I open them again and then test for non-ascii characters in the column (they are all filenames) and then report and go fix manually, but this is really inefficient and not ideal, especially when I have to iterate over these files many times. Do you think there is a way I can solve my problem programmatically or am I stuck with it as long as I have those values in my data?

Comment: you can probably bypass this by using `pandas` to read the data into a dataframe.  `openpyxl` is less friendly...

Comment: Hi @D.L - I also tried that, reading in as dtype=str, but the unwelcome values also existed in that output file after saving. For some reason that value is allowed to exist as 'correct' in Excel when editing inside Excel, but as soon as something else touches the file (openpyxl, pandas) the value is interpreted in an unfriendly way. I wish I knew more about this.

Comment: if you provide a minimal excel file (i dont have excel to produce one myself, but can read it), then i will show you how.

Comment: @D.L OK, thank you, I appreciate it. I've uploaded a the minimal file described above. Ideally there is a way to solve this for both Pandas and openpyxl, as some of my processes use both depending on what is happening to the data.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ahr3qFndIl2ViyhzQskXAmDCiJqugC_q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thansk.  answer is provided.

Comment: @D.L - see my comment beneath your answer.

Comment: Seeing as Pandas uses openpyxl to read the files any references to it for solving the problem are erroneous.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the example `xlsx` file.

i read this into a dataframe very simply in a few lines of code like this.

```py
import pandas as pd

file = 'c:/Users/admin/Downloads/StackExchange_Test/StackExchange_Test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)

print('here is the dataframe:')
print(df)
print('--------')

print('here is a value:')
print(df['Data_x4331_Problem'][0])
```

this is the output:

```
here is the dataframe:
   Data_x4331_Problem
0  Data_x4332_Problem
1  Data_x5141_Problem
2  Data_x5211_Problem
3  Data_x5213_Problem
--------
here is a value:
Data_x4332_Problem
```

It worked out of the box. I did not have to do anything extra...

You can also save the file like this:

- `df.to_excel()`
- `df.to_csv()`

i would prefer to save to csv.

example:

```py
new_file = 'c:/Users/admin/Downloads/StackExchange_Test/StackExchange_Test.csv'
df.to_csv(new_file)
```

And this works well and is fully readable.

Here is the csv file contents:

[image]

Comment: Hi @D.L - sorry, and I appreciate the effort, but I think you're missing part of my problem that was clearly explained in the first post with code and descriptive text. The data exists properly when loaded into Pandas or openpyxl. **It's only after a save operation via Pandas or openpyxl  that the value looks different when viewed in Excel than it does when examining the underlying xml.** In your example code you are only reading the file. Also, I cannot write to csv due to diacritics in other fields that must be preserved, plus this adds a lot of additional work to the processes.

Comment: @DavidA.  good feedback.  I am able to write csv or xlsx files perfectly fine too (tested both).  There is also a `df.to_xml()` method in pandas, so you can use that... I was fixing the difference, rather than explaining why it persists.

Comment: I can write to csv and xlsx fine with Pandas, but for csv I lose diacritics on other fields which means I cannot use that method, and when I save the xlsx via Pandas the value is still displayed incorrectly when viewed in Excel where my users interact with the data. I see in your first post you mentioned you do not have Excel so perhaps this explains why you cannot reproduce the results I've stated in my question and replies.